# HOW to download file, after publish App in IISExpress

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, download

Good day.
I want to download files from physical path in my server. when i run my application trough the vs2012 its work greate, and i see List of files from physical path. But when i publish the application on the server, the file is not in the list. I need to be sure to have any physical path, but the files should not be stored in the app package

Here code:

```
 public ActionResult NIRInfo()
{
    List<string> filesList = new List<string>();
    var dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"Z:\Docs");
    System.IO.FileInfo[] fileNames = dir.GetFiles("*.*");
    var xow = from i in db.NIRs where i.Id == id select i.File;
    foreach (var i in xow)
    {
        fileNames = dir.GetFiles(i);
        foreach (var f in fileNames)
        {
            filesList.Add(f.Name);
        }
        ViewData["fList"] = filesList;
    }
    return View(nir);

}
```

and code of class Download

```
public FileResult Download(string Name)
{
    return File(@"Z:\Docs\" + Name, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, Name); 
}
```

and code of view:

```
                        @{ var fList = ViewData["fList"] as List<string>;}

                        @if (ViewData["fList"] != null)
                        {
                            <table>
                                <div style="border-top: #444444 1px solid"></div>
                                <b style="font-weight: normal">Files: </b>
                                <br />
                                <div style="border-top: #444444 1px solid"></div>
                                @foreach (var f in fList)
                                {
                                    <a href="@Url.Action("Download", "NIR", new { Name = @f })">@f
                                        <br />
                                    </a> 
                                }
                            </table>
                        }
```

Comment: You are hard-coding the address in your code. Is it even the same path on the server side?

Comment: i think it may be path, for example : 192.xxx.xxx.xxx/Docs/Files

Comment: Then what do you expect? You're declaring the wrong path which isn't available on the server. The code is only doing what you're telling it to..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A assume that the path you specified on your local machine for the files are not the same as the one on the server. Meaning for example that on your local machine the files are located in "Z:\Docs", but on the server it might be "C:\Docs".

Since you are hard-coding the location in your application there is no way you could change it in the application after it is published, you would have to change it in the application and then republish it with the correct file path for the server.

This is a tedious process, I would rather recommend you add the location for the files to your web.config and use the value in web.config as the path for the files. This would mean you could publish the site to what ever server, with what ever path for the files and you could simply adjust the path in the web.config without having to republish the site every time.

You could add the key to your `<appSettings>` section of your web.config. like so

```
<add key="DownloadDocumentsPath" value="C:\Docs" />
```

and in your code you could then just read the value from the web.config, which would change your NIRInfo method to something like this:

```
public ActionResult NIRInfo()
{
    List<string> filesList = new List<string>();

    string fileDownloadPath =   System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DownloadDocumentsPath"];

    var dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@fileDownloadPath );
    System.IO.FileInfo[] fileNames = dir.GetFiles("*.*");
    var xow = from i in db.NIRs where i.Id == id select i.File;
    foreach (var i in xow)
    {
        fileNames = dir.GetFiles(i);
        foreach (var f in fileNames)
        {
            filesList.Add(f.Name);
        }
        ViewData["fList"] = filesList;
    }
    return View(nir);
}
```

And your Download method something like this:

```
public FileResult Download(string Name)
{
    string fileDownloadPath =     System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DownloadDocumentsPath"];
    return File(@fileDownloadPath + Name, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, Name); 
}
```

Comment: ok. thanks. I want to publish my App in IIS and after publish how can i get files?

Comment: If your set the path in the web.config file, like I explained in the post, to the correct path on the server where your files to be downloaded are located. Then the application should find the files if the directory exists. If the directory isn't found and Exception should be thrown. If that answers your question?